# Spring Resource Import fails

Tags: spring, resources

I am facing a strange issue with a spring project in netbeans. 
I have a set of context xmls say -
jms/myjms-context.xml - which internally loads jms.properties using property-placeholder
similarly thrs a jdbc context xml -
jdbc/myjdbc-context.xml - which internally loads jdbc.properties using property-placeholder
And these contexts needs to be imported as resources in my app-context.xml.

now if i import just one of these the application loads but when i import both i get an error with the property reference - "Could not resolve placeholder..." - in the second imported context (be it jms-context or jdbc-context)!!

What is going wrong?

-I am using Spring 3.0 and Spring integration 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` loaded into a spring context, as is your case, you need to set the `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders` to true so that the first one that will load, will ignore any placeholders that it can't resolve.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It did work!... just as, strangely, the individual imports were also working. Wud like to dig deeper sometime.. thanks a lot!.

Comment: @meer glad to know that it helped, but in that case, how about an upvote?